# How to do Matrix Chain Multiplication (MCM) with Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix-multiplication

I want to do MCM with threads of Java.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Is the problem how to actually do the multiplications or find the optimum order of the multiplications?

Comment: How about starting here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication